# UITableViewController with UISearchDisplayController not reloading data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a ViewController class with an appropriate .XIB file.  Here is the ViewController code:

**ViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{    
    NSArray *news;
    NSMutableData *data;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *mainTableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

@property (strong, nonatomic) Results *result;

@end
```

**ViewController.m:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Results.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize result, mainTableView, searchBar;

-(id) init
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

    if (self)
    {
        result = [[Results alloc] init];
        mainTableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
        [self.mainTableView setDelegate:self];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.title = @"Search";
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    NSString *query = searchBar.text;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://samplesite.com/external/metasearchjson.php?query=%@", query]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [data appendData:theData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSArray *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:NULL];

    if ([responseDict isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        news = responseDict;
        //[mainTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [[self mainTableView] reloadData];
        NSLog(@"%@", mainTableView);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"JSON Error.");
    }
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[indexPath row] inSection:0]];
    NSString *url = _getString([[news objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"link"]);
    [result getURL:url];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:result animated:YES];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The download could not complete - please make sure you're connected to either 3G or Wi-Fi." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorView show];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}

- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [news count];
}

NSString *_getString(id obj)
{
    return [obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] ? obj : nil;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = _getString([[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"metaScore"]);
    cell.textLabel.text = _getString([[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"]);

    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    return cell;
}
```

**My connections are all working, and the code successfully puts the JSON data into the UITableView.**

My problem is, the table view isn't reloading!

I have tried to just load it without a UISearchDisplayController, and it works fine.  I'm thinking it's some sort of override.  Where my TableView reloads data, that just doesn't work.  What's also weird is that if you type in something to the search display, the table view is displayed.  What am I doing wrong that the Search Bar doesn't reload the data?

Comment: If you use a search display controller, then you probably should reload the search results tableview: `[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData]`.

Comment: See my comments on the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your search display delegate, you need to implement

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
```

and return YES.

Comment: Nope, didn't work.  I added that to the `ViewController.m` file; I'm assuming that's what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Try make next steps:

In ViewController.h:

add protocols:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

add property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* news;
```

then replace in connectionDidFinishLoading: method news = responseDict; as

```
self.news = responseDict;
```

then perform reloadData in main thread:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[self mainTableView] reloadData];
    });
```

in ViewController.m insert line [self.mainTableView setDataSource: self]; :

```
-(id) init
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

    if (self)
    {
...
        [self.mainTableView setDelegate:self];
        [self.mainTableView setDataSource: self];
    }

    return self;
}
```

hope it helps you.

Comment: After some debugging, I found that the dictionary is loaded up fine.  Also, the table view is hooked up, as I tried hiding it under where I reload the data.  The only thing that doesn't seem to be called is reloadData.

Comment: So why don't you think reloadData is being called?

Comment: you should set up ViewController as datasource delegate. See in my answer.

Comment: Now it's getting really weird.  I implemented that code and instead of `[[self mainTableView] reloadData]` I did `[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData]`.  This works **only** when the search display controller has focus.  When I click cancel in the search display controller, the results are hidden.

Comment: your code contains a lot of questions. you need study this article: http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view